# PHP - splice array alphabetically after some letter

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, alphabetical, letter

I´m looking for a solution to get all words (or numbers) from a sorted array AFTER some letter or number. I.e. all countries after letter K.

```
$countries = array(
'Luxembourg', 
'Germany', 
'France', 
'Spain', 
'Malta',
'Portugal', 
'Italy', 
'Switzerland', 
'Netherlands',  
'Belgium', 
'Norway', 
'Sweden', 
'Finland', 
'Poland',
'Lithuania', 
'United Kingdom', 
'Ireland', 
'Iceland',
'Hungary', 
'Greece', 
'Georgia'
);

sort($countries);
```

That will return Belgium, Finland, France, Georgia, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Italy, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, ...

But I want only countries AFTER letter K: Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `array_filter` function to filter out the stuff you don't want.

```
$result = array_filter( $countries, function( $country ) {
  return strtoupper($country{0}) > "K";
});
```

Comment: Please note that anonymous functions are only available in PHP 5.3+. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Hmm.. that returns an empty array?

Comment: Use `strtoupper` and compare with a uppercase letter, or the other way with lowercase.

Comment: That does the trick. Following question: Does that work with digits like 2014_12_03, 2014_12_01, 2014_11_30 too, so that all after 2014_12_02 show up?

Comment: Possibly, but it would be a much better idea to convert such strings to DateTime objects and compare those. More reliable that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$countries2 = array();
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    if(strtoupper($country[0]) > "K") break;
    $countries2[] = $country;
}
```

Comment: That comes close. What if there are numbers in the array like 2014_12_02 or 2014_11_30? Is there an option to separate all after 2014_12_01?

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a simple solution to splice an array after any delimiter. Even if it´s not a letter or digit (like "2013_12_03"). Just insert the wanted delimiter into the array, then order, then splice:

```
//dates array:
$dates = array(
'2014_12_01_2000_Jazz_Night',
'2014_12_13_2000_Appletowns_Christmas',
'2015_01_24_2000_Jazz_Night',
'2015_02_28_2000_Irish_Folk_Night',
'2015_04_25_2000_Cajun-Swamp-Night',
'2015_06_20_2000_Appeltowns_Summer_Session'
);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');//if needed
$today = date(Y."_".m."_".d);//2014_12_03 for delimiter (or any other)
$dates[] = $today;//add delimiter to array
sort($dates);//sort alphabetically (with your delimiter)


$offset = array_search($today, $dates);//search position of delimiter
array_splice($dates, 0, $offset);//splice at delimiter
array_splice($dates, 0, 1);//delete delimiter
echo "<br>next date:<br>".$dates[0];//array after your unique delimiter
```

Hope that helps all who wants to splice a naturally ordered array after something.